# jquery class selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to properly select a class inside the menu.

It worked fine until I put the menu in a ul. Can anyone tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/7XrUk/

Comment: which class are you referring to in that example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The problem is that you're calling `index` on the link, which is a child of the `li`, and so will always only be the first child. You want the index of its parent instead.

Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/7XrUk/1/

Comment: This works great! How would I select the div for collapse instead of the ul? Ive tried but can seem understand how it works.http://jsfiddle.net/7XrUk/1/

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7XrUk/5/ Just swap out the `ul` for `div` in the selector. My guess is it didn't appear to work for you because you forgot to change the first line, which hides all `ul` children to instead hide all the `div` children?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/3hbk7/

```
var $menuelement = $('.demo ul').eq($(this).index());//find the matching nth element in the menu
```

…should’ve been:

```
var $menuelement = $('.demo ul').eq($(this).parent().index());//find the matching nth element in the menu
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was something little. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty vague, but this is the concept if the child is nested:

`$('.menu').find('.class')`